# How to identify appended list in list

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a listbox that is bind with a datasource. In this listbox I have done selection of items as multiextended. And I am holding that items which I have selected from listbox like below code.

```
selectedreportRow = lstSelectRows.SelectedItems.Cast<FRReportRow>().ToList();
```

Now I am appending a new selection of listbox in the "selectedreportRow" list as below code.

```
 if (selectedreportRow.Count > 0)
 {
   appendReportRow=lstSelectRows.SelectedItems.Cast<FRReportRow>().ToList();
   selectedreportRow.AddRange(appendReportRow);
 }
```

if I give an example for above description it is just like this.

*1st list* :  `45, 234, 4634, 2342, 23421, 534, 76`

*list with appended list* : `45, 234, 4634, 2342, 23421, 534, 76 , 656, 86,454`

How can I identify the second list that my first list was of till "76" items? I am appending list again and again, and I also want replace last list with new selection of listbox.

Comment: are you appending same items everytime?

Comment: yes..at the same listbox.If listbox contains items from 1 to 10.and first time i select 1, 2, 3 items and second time i select 7, 8 and append it and one time i select 4 .it just like 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 4.So I want to identify every list separately So i can replace only last list from new list.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the items you add in a separate list. Before adding new items, you can remove the last added items.

```
appendReportRow=lstSelectRows.SelectedItems.Cast<FRReportRow>().ToList();

lastAddedItems.ForEach(a => selectedreportRow.Remove(a));
lastAddedItems.Clear();
lastAddedItems.AddRange(appendReportRow);

selectedreportRow.AddRange(appendReportRow);
```

You need to instantiate `lastAddedItems` earlier and initially it should be empty.

Comment: No I can not clear full list.I only want to replace only last list which i append recently.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a lot solution for this. Just declare a variable which holds the last element of your original list. (if the data is unique) If it is not just store the index of the last element.